# Beginner Python: Division in a while loop

Tags: python, loops, iteration, division

My goal here is to repeat this code using .01 as the base, then .001, and so on 6 times. Using a while loop, how could I run the code once with .01 as the base then divide it 10? How could I repeat that process 6 times?
I tried using the /= operator but I get a syntax error.

```
print("Computing the area under the curve x^2 + x + 1")
a = int(input("Enter the left end point a: x = "))
b = int(input("Enter the left end point b: x = "))
    
base = 0.1
x = a 
total_area = 0
    
while a <= x and x <= b:
        area = (x**2 + x + 1) * base
        x += base
        total_area += area
    
print("Area under the curve between 40 and 60 using dx =", '{:.0E}'.format(base) , '{:.6f}'.format(total_area))
```

Comment: It would help to show what you tried that generated a syntax error, as well as the exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

A for-loop alternative:

```py
print("Computing the area under the curve x^2 + x + 1")
a = int(input("Enter the left end point a: x = "))
b = int(input("Enter the left end point b: x = "))
    
base = 0.1
iterations = 6

for i in range(iterations):
    total_area = 0
    x = a
    
    while a <= x and x <= b:
            area = (x**2 + x + 1) * base
            x += base
            total_area += area
    
    print("Area under the curve between 40 and 60 using dx =", '{:.0E}'.format(base) , '{:.6f}'.format(total_area))
    base /= 10
```